# Array out of Bounds exceptions in OSMdroid, during update from AsyncTask

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, osmdroid

I'm trying to update UI from AsyncTask for MapView. After many trials, I keep getting this exception error. I've put try/catch most of the places, yet still I get the error.

**Here is Logcat error:**

```
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedOverlay.getItem(ItemizedOverlay.java:158)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ItemizedOverlay.drawSafe(ItemizedOverlay.java:125)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.SafeDrawOverlay.draw(SafeDrawOverlay.java:85)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayManager.onDraw(OverlayManager.java:141)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchDraw(MapView.java:1024)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2381)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2253)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1883)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-20 16:19:22.273: E/AndroidRuntime(26776):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
```

Comment: in which method of Asynchtask you update the UI ?
can you please update your code here ?

Comment: Your array is empty check size if possible before calling array element of certain index which in your case is 2

Comment: @gyanu I'm checking size and null both before proceeding

Comment: @GovindRathod In progressUpdate() I'm updating the UI, and infact the log messages doesn't show the update of any of my *.java files, but rather it shows `OSMdroid` Library files.

Comment: Probably you might look on configuration and project settings so that you get proper data from Maps api call.

Comment: @gyanu I checked my config , seems alright!

Comment: You have added only log in question.We don't know how you are dealing with your code.I can't say much on this.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can read out of the log, you are trying to access an array that does not have a length yet. When creating the array or before acessing it you need to initalize it by giving it a certain length. In Java, it looks something like this:

```
int [] arrayExcample;
arrayExcample = new int [10];
```

This array contains a total of 10 free "spaces" for Integer values now. If you want an other type of data, just replace the two "int" by it.

If you want to shorten your code you could also use the following, depending on the context, to implement your Array:

```
int [] arrayExcample = new int [10];
```

Comment: I've initialized my ArrayList, if you notice my log messages, I've no exception in my *.java file, but rather on `OSMdroid` library. So, this is constantly happening when I'm trying to draw very fast.

Comment: It might be a Thread issue then. Have you tried syncronizing your methods?

Comment: Yes, I've sync my threads, and its AsyncTask nothing much to sync